# Adaptec RAID 5 degraded but all HDD are reported as optimal

Tags: raid, adaptec

According to adaptec support site, data on a disk got corrupted. The disk is physically fine and thats why it shows up as optimal. The solution is to reinitialize the disk. The only problem is I can't figure out which disk has the problem. Adaptec Storage Manager just says raid is degraded and all disks are optimal with no more information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk that caused this should no longer be part of the active array. Maybe it was re-assigned as the hotspare or you need to scan for un-assigned hard disks?

Comment: Looks like the drive was simply removed from the list instead of being marked as bad. Your comment helped narrow that down for me. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Thanks for reporting back and letting me know my bitter and hard-earned experience is useful.